# Can't get tabhost tab widget to populate

Tags: android, sqlite, android-tabhost

I have a issue with an application I am trying to get done by 11:59 pm tonight, I am working with a SQLite db for android and it is suppose to populate with a new list title coming from the database. The thing is it is not. What I doing is calling an activity from a Actionbar menu item which starts the new intent.

```
case R.id.menuAddList:
            Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, AddListActivity.class);
            listIntent.putExtra("tab", tabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
            startActivity(listIntent);
            break;
```

When I get to this activity I can edit the text with an editext widget which updates the list column in the database, this is fine and the database is updated with the new list item. Here is the code for that.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuSave:
            saveToDatbase();
            this.finish();
            break;
        case R.id.menuCancel:
            this.finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void saveToDatbase() {
    // Get the data from the widgets
    int listID = addlistSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
    String name = newListNameEditText.getText().toString();


    // If there is no item name, then exit the method
    if ( name == null || name.equals("")) {
        return;
    }

    // If in add mode, create a new list item
    if(!editMode) {
        list = new List();
    }

    // Put some data in the list
    list.setId(listID);
    list.setName(name);


    // Update or insert item data
    if(editMode) {
        db.updateList(list);

    }
    else {
        db.insertList(list);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
        // Hide the soft keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        saveToDatbase();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

The thing is when I either click the add item icon or the back button on my device the new list object is not populated on the new tab unless I quit the application and return to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the list stored in the list adapter you gave the listview.

```
mListAdapter.setList(****new data****);
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mList.invalidate();
```

The setList function puts the new data into the adapter. Setlist is a custom function and will have to be placed inside your custom adapter. Calling notifyDataSetChanged should reload the adapter and invalidating the listview will reload the listview and display the new information.